# Regex: split a string on whitespace + each special character to be included separately

Tags: javascript, regex

How would I write use regexp to split a string like so:

```
"foo bar, foobar (bar)" => ["foo", "bar", ",", "foobar", "(", "bar", ")"]
```

i.e. split on whitespace + each special character should separately get included in the resulting array

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: I am using JavaScript

Comment: What output are you looking to obtain? It would help if you didn't repeat foo-bar constantly; use apples, pears, bananas or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of splitting, I'd do the reverse; find all matches of `\w+|[^\w\s]`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense indeed!

Comment: I want the underscore to be treated as a special character as well. So I tried modifying the regex to `_|\w+|[^\w\s]`. But it doesn't seem to work. Help please?

Comment: @HimanshuP: Special character as in not allowed to match? In that case you could do `[a-zA-Z0-9]|[^\w\s]`

Comment: @HimanshuP Try `[A-Za-z0-9]+|[^A-Za-z0-9\s]` to count underscores as punctuation.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do something like this

```
var foo = []; 
"foo bar, foobar (bar)".split(/(\W)/).forEach(function(elem) {
    if (!/^\s*$/.test(elem)) { 
        foo.push(elem);
    }
}); 
// foo = (object) ['foo', 'bar', ',', 'foobar', '(', 'bar', ')']
```

The new array "foo" will contain all your values.

Answer (score 2):

You can split on the following regex:

```
"\s|(?=\W)"
```

Well, this one will give you following output:

```
["foo", "bar", ",", "foobar", "", "(bar", ")"]
```

Since, Javascript *doesn't support look-behinds*, it wouldn't be possible here to split to break `(bar` into two separate elements.

A better way would be to *match* instead of *split*. All you want is to get all the substrings matching the following regex pattern:

```
"\w+|[^\w\s]"
```

To use `_` as special characters, you can use:

```
"[^_\W]+|[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]"
```

Comment: This is the output I get using that `["foo", "bar", ",", "foobar", "(bar", ")"]`
It's close but `"(bar"` should have been two separate tokens.

Comment: @HimanshuP. Yeah I realized it as I posted. I'm working on it.

Comment: I want the underscore to be treated as a special character as well. So I tried modifying the regex to `_|\w+|[^\w\s]`. But it doesn't seem to work. Help please?

Comment: Thanks, it works! Just so that I know, why does `_|\w+|[^\w\s]` not work?

Comment: Because `\w` includes the `_`. So once you start matching the sequence with `\w+`, it will go on matching `_` too. `\w` is equivalent to - `[_0-9a-zA-Z]`

Comment: Okay, and the `_` at the beginning of `_|\w+|[^\w\s]` is ignored since the *longest matching sequence* is considered to be the match -- is that right?

Comment: @HimanshuP. No, not like that. If the `_` is found first in the string, it will be matched by `_` part of your regex. But, if `_` is somewhere in between words - `ABC_DF`, it will be matched by `\w+`.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with `(\w+|[,()])` per http://rubular.com/r/BGAFLOmkgP